# facebook og:image does not fetch image from php file that echoes the URL

Tags: php, facebook-opengraph

facebook OG fetch image from echoed URL, is this possible?

since I included a php file that will echo the image URL but when I check in Sharing debugger the content is empty

`<meta property="og:image" content="" />`
[image]

**my meta tag** **:**

`<meta property="og:image" content ="<?php include "meta_gambar.php"?>">`

**and the php file :**

```
<?php
 $module=$_GET['module'];
 $id=$_GET['id'];
 if($module=='detailproduk'){
   //prepare query
   $stmt=mysqli_prepare($con,"SELECT gambar FROM produk WHERE id_produk=?");
    if($stmt===false){
       die("Prepare error" . htmlspecialchars($mysqli->error));
    }
    //Bind parameters
    $bp=mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"i",$id);
     if($bp===false){
        die("Binding error" . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }
     //Execute query
     $bp=mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     if($bp===false){
         die("Execute error" . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
     }
     //bind result
     $bp=mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt,$gambar);
      if($bp===false){
          die("Result bind error" . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
      }
     //Fetch
      $bp=mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
       if($bp===false){
           die("Fetching error" .htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
      }
    $image = "http://images.rajafotocopy.com/foto_produk/$gambar";
   }else{
      $image = "http://images.rajafotocopy.com/raja.png";
 }
   echo"$image";
?>
```

**Update**

I just tried putting a direct URL image to the `og:image content` and it works

[image]

but including a php file that will echo the URL still results in blank

Comment: so my code should work.... but why is this happening?

Comment: I have, the resutl is like that `<meta property="og:image" content="" />`

Comment: There are issues with your code, though. You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not even escaping your inputs.

Comment: Another thing, Your SQL-code does not handle errors, but rather suppressing them (which is a bad bad thing when debugging, like now). Handle them correctly instead (read the manual). If your query don't return any results, your code will break since you're trying to use the result anyway. If your `if`-statement don't evaluates, you're still trying to echo an undefined variable.

Comment: i thought prepared statement should be used for user input not select query to fetch image?

Comment: You should remove all `@`-signs, check your error log and turn on `display_errors` while you develop. That might give you a bunch of useful information.

Comment: `where id_produk='$_GET[id]'"` ... the `$_GET['id']` is user input (query string)

Comment: ok... although that is not really a user input since I don't make a user controlled form or things, but I will use a prepared statements and remove the `@` wait I'll edit

Comment: If the user can change a value (like he/she can in this case, since `$_GET['id']` is in the URL in the browser), it's considered user input. The user can write `http://...?id=whatever`

Comment: I tried running the php file and it's echoing the result fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the current path is not where the include file is.  Try specifying the full path to the include file, eg:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/path/to/meta_gambar.php";
```

Another option is to use `require` instead of `include` - if there is a problem with the file or path, `require` will generate an error and give you some ideas about what is wrong.

Comment: not that. I use og:description to generate description with another php file, this php is file located in the same path with meta_gambar.php. the file in og:description echoed a string, and opengraph get it. but file in og:image echoed a URL to an image and opengraph does not get it, the content is left blank. I also tried og:url just to confirm my suspicion of "it cannot get an echoed URL" by echoing a variable with `h t t p ://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and that's it. the content is blank.  

OG cannot get an echoed URL from a variable inside a PHP file

Comment: but it can get an echoed string from inside a variable from php file

Comment: OK. But don't complicate your issue - Facebook's debugger has nothing to do with it.  It is just parsing the html you give it.  If it fails, you're giving it bad HTML.  Either `meta_gambar.php` is not echoing a string, or something is wrong with the include.  What does the og tags of of your main page look like (I mean view->source from a browser)?

Comment: this is what I get from sharing debugger and object debugger `<meta property="og:image" content="" /> `. that is what I also get from view source of browser. why is that? why can't it echo an URL? I ran the script and it echoed the URL fine

Comment: Don't use Facebook debugger, just view source of your local file.  Delete all code in `meta_gambar.php`, and add just 1 line: `echo "http://images.rajafotocopy.com/raja.png";`.  Now what does source in the main file look like?

Comment: ok now meta_gambar.php only contains `<?php
echo "http://images.rajafotocopy.com/raja.png";
?>` but the page view source still blank

Comment: OK, so there is something wrong with the include - path, permissions, something like that.  Have you tried `require` as I suggested above, to see if any errors are shown?  Is there anything in PHP or Apache error logs?

Comment: ok. I will try, but now I need to rest, I've been working on this problem since yesterday morning.... thank you, I will be back

Comment: using require or require_once solves the problem but, it makes access to the image forbidden, hence it will not show the image. what I'm trying to say is, I use image "A" for opengraph but then I also use image "A" on a certain page, while this image is being used for opengraph. do you have solution so I don't need to use image "A-2" because that would doubles the resource?

Comment: I don't understand the problem ... you can use an image as many times as you like.  I also don't understand how `require` worked but `include` did not.  Did require show you some error msgs which you were able to fix?